# How do I change canvas height or parent in tkinter outside of a funtion?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

so I'm very new to programming and especially with python, and I still don't know how to work with object oriented programming so I haven't been working with that.

I wanted to create a couple of scrollable frames in tkinter, and I didn't want to write the same code for every frame again and again, and since I don't work with object oriented programming yet I created this helper function:

```
def scrolled_frame(frame):

    canvas = Canvas(frame, height=550, width=root.winfo_screenwidth() - 120)
    canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL)))
    second_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=second_frame)
    return second_frame
```

Because I want to add another frame beneath the canvas that could be opened and closed, I want to be able to play with canvas height outside of the function. Clearly if I'm declaring canvas inside this function that I wrote, that would be impossible! So I was wondering if there's a way to declare the canvas outside the function yet set it's frame in the function.. or also if there's another solution I'd be glad to hear!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can return both `second_frame` and `canvas` at the end of the function so that you can modify the canvas later on.

Comment: @j_4321 but then I still have to set the canvas height every time again and again depending on the parent frame

Comment: I don't get your question, it seemed to me your problem was having access to the canvas outside the function

Comment: When you say "So I was wondering if there's a way to declare the canvas outside the function yet set its frame in the function" are you talking about `second_frame` ? because if so, you can create the canvas outside the function and pass it as an argument. It's hard to answer because I don't understand the bigger picture about what you want to do. Maybe if you added a code example with this extra frame you want to add and in which way you need to change the canvas, that would help clarify the problem.

Comment: no I'm talking about `frame`, for example if the functions returns `second_frame` and canvas so I have to do:

`insert_frame_helper = tk.Frame(root)

insert_frame=scrolled_frame(insert_frame_helper)[0]

insert_canvas=scrolled_frame(insert_frame_helper)[1]

update_frame_helper = tk.Frame(root)
updare_frame=scrolled_frame(update_frame_helper)[0]
update_canvas=scrolled_frame(update_frame_helper)[1]

and then for each canvas:
insert_canvas["height"] = 400
update_canvas["height"] = 400`

And I have mutiple frames so I don't wanna repeat the same code...

@j_4321

Comment: Please edit the question so that the code can be formated, it's hard to read in the comments

Comment: yes sorry, I'm trying to fix that @j_4321

Comment: `insert_frame_helper = tk.Frame(root)  

insert_frame=scrolled_frame(insert_frame_helper)[0]  

insert_canvas=scrolled_frame(insert_frame_helper)[1] 

update_frame_helper = tk.Frame(root) 

updare_frame=scrolled_frame(update_frame_helper)[0] 

update_canvas=scrolled_frame(update_frame_helper)[1]  

insert_canvas["height"] = 400 

update_canvas["height"] = 400`

Comment: @j_4321 I hope this is more readable, I don't know how to insert new line in comments

Comment: You don't need to call `scrolled_frame(...)` twice to get the frame and canvas, just one call is enough: `insert_frame, insert_canvas = scrolled_frame(...)`.